# Seamless Tri-polygon

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes, patterns

Is it even possible to make a **seamless** tri-polygon in photoshop? I've tried (please see the following) but it didn't turn out well. The color of the picture can simply be a base color, no gradient is fine too.

*- The grey one (First picture) is seamless but as you can see the shapes is very messy and uneven*

*- The brown one (Second picture) is the original version (non seamless)*

[image: Here is a seamless picture but as you can see the shapes is very messy and uneven]

[image: Here's the original version (non-seamless)]

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you must use photohop

Comment: @joojaa no particular reason, just more used to photoshop that's all. if i have to use other software like illustrator i'm fine with that too. just need to make a seamless tri-polygon. :)

Comment: Yeah i understand how conflation artefacts work

Comment: Could you guide me please? I'm new to this, i know how to make normal shapes work but because it's tri-polygon it's not as easy.

Comment: @Cheryl there are [tutorials for this on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Photoshop+low+poly+tutorial).

Comment: @BillyKerr followed the tutorials on youtube but the seamless part is not right, it is not seamless at all, very uneven :(

Comment: Do you require a gradient as you've shown in the image? If so, it will have to be a "center-out" type of gradient, as the seamless aspect requires that the edges of the foundation image are identical, left to right and top to bottom.

Comment: @fred_dot_u no i do not require a gradient, it can be just a basic base color :)

Comment: I have updated the pictures of the tri-polygons above :)

(First picture) is seamless but as you can see the shapes are very messy and uneven.
(Second picture) is the original version (non-seamless) 

:)

Comment: Use a delaunay triangulation on a uniform, or cellular uniform seed field. By the way your first picture has a few conflation artefacts too.

Comment: When you say seamless, do you mean you want to use it as a seamless tile for  filling a background?  It's not easy to do something like this with a pattern like the one you show, but there are tutorials on youtube that should give you some ideas.

Comment: Yeah gonna use it as a background wall. I know it's not easy and I've tried but it's not working out :( the tutorials on youtube doesnt help much when it comes to seamless...

Comment: Ok. I've added an answer now.  It's not a full tutorial, merely a guide on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the Pen Tool, and set it to "Shape" in the tool options.
2. Set up a 10px grid and enable Snap to Grid to make it easier to join up the polygons exactly.
3. Draw a low poly pattern, filling in the triangles different colours, but don't go all the way to the edges of the design.
4. Do *Layer > Flatten image*, then *Filter > Other > Offset*, to offset the pattern using multiples of 10px for both x and y values. This will allow you to move the pattern around so you can edit different parts of it.
5. Continue with the design, and fill in the blank areas with more triangles.
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5, until you have no more blank areas left.
7. To remove conflation artefacts (the gaps between the polygons), flatten the final image and do *Filter > Other > Minimum*, and set the radius to 0.5px

Now the pattern will be seamless and tileable.

Here's a quick example I made using the above technique. Obviously your example is much larger and more complex so it will take you much longer. Anyway, here's the seamless pattern:

[image]

And here's an example using it as a pattern fill:

[image]

Comment: One of your shapes is not a triangle! [Example](https://imgur.com/rQWca8V)

Comment: @PieBie ooooops!!

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks for the idea! :) i have managed to make one too myself :) https://imgur.com/a/tydSgKF :)